# Не воспроизводиться видео на RawImage

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня проблема с воспроизведением видео на RawImage, у многих её тоже видел в интернете, но решения так и не нашел, при этом у большенства работает. Мне нужно показать видео в канвасе, увидел что для этого нужно RawImage, и текстуру с видео перекинуть на RawImage, но вот же не работает, код следующий:

```
public RawImage rawImage;
public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

void Awake ()
{
    rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
}
```

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=51&v=GC23c4ds4lg)

Comment: Лично я бы на твоем месте копал бы в сторону того какие форматы сжатия и какие контейнеры видео этот видеоплеер поддерживает. Скорее всего дело именно в этом и ты пихаешь туда видео которое банально не поддерживается.

Comment: @Andrew уже нашел ответ на вопрос, с новой версии юнити, там нельзя просто текстуру передать как аргумент, точнее со стороны кода ошибки не будет, а на деле ничего, нужно было создать отдульную текстуру в проекте, на которую будет транслироваться видео, и потом хоть куда пихать её.

Comment: Оформите полноценный ответ, иначе нет смысла в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решения проблемы: нужно не присваивать текстуру из VideoPlayer, а транслировать видео на созданную Render Texture, которая уже должна лежать в RawImage